# Check permissions on a set of AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an app where users are required to enter in a set of AWS credentials with a specific set of permissions. I'd like to verify the credentials when they are entered in to make sure they have the required set of user policies on them.

Is there a way I can retrieve the user policies for those credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *if* they gave you creds that are allowed to do an IAM call. You can list all their IAM users, then find the one IAM user with your key, and then read the permissions for that user. But this requires parsing the IAM permissions language, which is a little complex.

The other way to do it is make a sample call for anything you want to verify (i.e. list S3 bucket, etc.) It's probably better to validate just one or two calls than try to validate every possible call. Yes, you're likely to run into errors down the road if you're missing some permissions, but it's much more likely that they made a typo or gave you the wrong creds than they gave you partial creds.

The other thing you could consider: If they give you full creds, you could create an IAM user with just the creds you need, an use those creds.  Everything in IAM has an API, so it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, IAM is not one of the permissions I require right now, was hoping there would be some way for a credential to list its own permissions.
I'm basically doing exactly what you're suggesting right now - validating each permission set by making API calls - was just hoping there would be a less cumbersome way to do it.